# AutoPlay and loop video upon loading of webpage

Tags: html, html5-video

How to autoplay a video as soon as page loads(not youtube video) and loop it infinitely in HTML while using FLASK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. Add muted property to `autoplay` `<video src="test.mp4" width="30%" height="20%" controls autoplay **muted** loop></video>`

Flask

```html
{% block content %}

<video src="test.mp4" width="30%" height="20%" controls autoplay **muted** loop></video>

{% endblock %}
```